# Add two background colors to an element

Tags: css

Is it possible to have something like this :[image]
So I have an element

```
 <span class="custom"> 6 </span>
```

that has this css:

```
 background: lightblue;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 50px;
```

When selected.
This creates the circle. But what I need is that this element has also a background with lighter blue, that is not rounded.
Is it possible to some way achieve this and have the element have two background ?
The circle one being on top ?

Comment: Are you trying to add a gradient or have the element switch colors when you hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linear-gradient with pseudo element to achieve the second background like this :

```css
.custom {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 50%, red 0%);
  z-index: -2
}
```

```html
<span class="custom">6</span>
```

Comment: Haha, that was about to be messed up.

Comment: @Highdef i simply put it smaller :)

Comment: I updated an edit, to just use flex and no more padding to deal with. You may use that if you wish. :)

Comment: @Highdef sorry but i got rejected by Community as too many changes .. but it's not a big deal as the alignement isn't the issue here

Comment: @TemaniAfif for some reason when I do this, The red goes on top of the blue background. 
Still behind the number, but on top of the rounded background :|

Comment: @MonnIca try to decrease `z-index:-1` put something lower and see if it works

Comment: No. I also tried giving span a z-index bigger z-index, but still same.

Comment: @MonnIca is there a way you can share a link with me so i can see ?

Comment: @Temani [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zo0lOqG1MO4k9hAxtOfs?p=preview) . Now it won't show at all.
The selected date ( the first one ) should have the background color.
The css is on the html file.

Comment: @MonnIca ok i see the issue ... i updated my solution then, to use two pseudo element one for the cercle and one the background, it should work now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a div container to have the linear gradient background and another div inside it containing the circular div with 6 in the center aligned using flexbox.

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 50%, #aaaaff 0%);
  width: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.custom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #7070ff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="custom"> 6 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think the idea is to keep only one element. By the way in the gradient you can simply specify 2 colors by makeing the % of second one lower than the first ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif What do you mean by keeping one element? As in applying the style everything on a single element?

Comment: i meant that you add a container for the second background ... but i think (am not sure) he's looking to only have the span he specified without extra html

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well, his query started with him just wanting something to make it look like that screenshot, so I don't think he has it restricted on how to accomplish that.

Comment: yes that's why i said am not sure, as in the title he also said `Add two background colors to an element`

Comment: It's a she haha. And Thank you both!
I apologize I wasn't specific. I cannot alter the html, because I am using ng bootstrap calendar template. I just need to alter the css of the span ( which would be the selected date) to have both a color in a circle, and a behind background color

Comment: @MonnIca my apologies, sorry for the **he** :)

Comment: @MonnIca Same here, haha apologies :)

Comment: @MonnIca you can then check my solution where i didn't alter the HTML ;)

Comment: @MonnIca Yeah and I helped him make it rounder haha x)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Highdef - Thank you so much both!
I was just trying to adapt your solution to the calendar  cuz it messes up the rest of it hah

Comment: @MonnIca No problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use two element on each other then set background with opacity lower than 1 for upper element now you have two background.